# Is the return type wrong?

Tags: c++, return, operator-overloading

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class binary
{
protected:
    int num;
public:
    binary(int a)
    {
        num=a;
    }
    binary operator - (binary b1)
    {
        binary b(0);
        b.num=~(b1.num-1);
        return b(b.num);
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<"Negative is: "<<num;
    }
};
int main()
{
    int a;
    cout<<"Enter no.: ";
    cin>>a;
    binary b(a);
    binary b1=-b;
    b1.display();
}
```

In the above program, it shows that the return type of overloading operator should be should be of form int&. Can anyone please explain to me what that means?

Comment: `return b(b.num);` is not right. It should be `return b;`. Is that where you see the error?

Comment: If you want to overload unary minus, it’s `operator-()` with no parameters; the operand is `this`.

Comment: It is not necessary that an `operator-()` return a reference.  It is usually appropriate that it return by value, since an expression `a - b` gives a result that is neither `a` nor `b`.    There is usually a benefit (for the binary `operator-()`) that the second operand be passed by `const` reference - but that's not what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is the return type wrong ?* yes returning `b(b.num);` is wrong, it should return only object `b`.

You are overloading `unary` minus  using `member function`, it should have zero argument because `member function` having `this` pointer, you can use this pointer to get `data member` of class.

```
 binary operator - () 
 {
         binary b(0);
         b.num = ~(this-> num-1);
         return b;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You improperly declared the unary `operator-`. There are two variants of `operator-`: *unary* and *binary*. Since `this` is implicitly on the left hand of `operator-`, unary operator requires no arguments and binary requires one argument on the right hand. Therefore you declared binary `operator-`. Please try like below

```
binary operator - ()
{
    return binary(~(num-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
binary operator-(binary b1) { ... }
```

defines the binary `-` operator between two objects of type `binary`.

To be able to use

```
binary b1=-b;
```

you need to overload the unary `-` operator. That can be done using:

```
binary operator-() { ... }
```

I suspect you want to implement the unary `-` operator. Your implementation can use `this` instead of `b1`. I suggest making he member function `const` since it does not modify the `this` object.

```
binary operator-() const
{
   binary b(~(this->num-1));
   return b;
}
```

That will also allow you to use:

```
binary b1 = -binary(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Because you have to parse integer value** 
But as given in code return b(b.num)
instead of that it should be "return b".